# Block cross domain XHR or fetch call at origination/source

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, fetch-api, content-security-policy

Let's consider the following scenario:

- a user loads `https://foo.com/index.html` in one of the modern browsers which allow `CORS`.
- `index.html` loads a javascript from `https://bar.com/script.js` via the `script` tag.
- considering a hypothetical situation where this `script.js` is never cached and the content of `script.js` has changed.
- `script.js` makes an `XHR` request to `https://baz.com`
- `https://baz.com` has enabled `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: *` thus this `XHR` made by `script.js` goes through.
- important user information now can be passed to `https://baz.com` which is a security risk.

Prior to `CORS`, `XHR` calls were strictly followed same-origin policy and thus calls to `https://baz.com` from `https://foo.com` would not be permitted by the browsers.

I am wondering if there is a way for `https://foo.com/index.html` to specify a list of `XHR` permissible domain names so that the above scenario would not be possible.

Any pointer is highly appreciated.

**[UPDATED]**

[I guess I have found the answer to my question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670659/block-cross-domain-xhr-or-fetch-call-at-origination-source/#answer-55670717)

Thank you for being considerate

Best!

Answer (score 4):

I guess I found the answer to my question.

Using `connect-src` directive of the `Content-Security-Policy` Header `https://foo.com/` can restrict the `XHR`, `fetch` calls along with `WebSocket`, `EventSource`, `<a> ping` to desired domains.

```
Content-Security-Policy: connect-src <source> <source>;
```

More information at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src

*I once thought of deleting my question but someone else like me can be benefited.*

Comment: I was going to post an answer about how to overload XMLHttpRequest and fetch() to create  interceptors...this is much simpler!

Answer (score 0):

CORS blocking is done on the server side, where the response headers are set to allow requests from certain origins or not.

If `bar.com/script.js` fetches data from `baz.com`, then `baz.com` should have the CORS restriction.